# How to persist a workflow input variable in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

For one of my GitHub projects I have a couple of workflows. They work fine, but now I would like to have a maintenance mode. Meaning that if the project is in maintenance they should run a little bit differently.

The way I would like this to work, is that I have one workflow which is triggered manually. The others are triggered by commits. The manual workflow also requires me to fill in a value for the maintenance input/variable. So far everything is fine:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      maintenance:
        description: 'Set MAINTENANCE variable'
        required: true
        default: 'false'  # Default value if not provided

...
```

How to persist this maintenance value in GitHub such that the other workflows can access this value and do their magic?

Is this possible, or should I manually modify this `MAINTENANCE` in GitHub?

Comment: Why _not_ just set the [variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables) directly? Even if you knew how to do it (https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_variable_set), what's the benefit of having to manually trigger a workflow to automatically set the value instead of just manually setting the value?

Comment: I always try to do as little as possible manually :) Also, this maintenance workflow does other things to. So I thought that it would be nice if it could also set this variable too. Thnx for the `gh_variable_set` link! I'll check it out

Comment: But even so you could set the variable, then manually trigger the workflow _without_ the input - same amount of work.